# How to upgrade an existing React Native App to new React native version? Do we have any documentation?

Tags: react-native

Do we have any documentation which could help in upgrading React native version within an existing React native App?

Since, new React native version 0.62.0 is recently released which also includes Flipper and Hermes, would require some help while including them within Android and IPhone native code.

Answer (score 1):

Great that you found an answer, the main problem is when you have to upgrade from RN version 0.59< to 0.59 and beyond. After 0.59 there was autolinking which was implemented for native packages.  For that ive followed a document, hope it helps. [upgrade](https://medium.com/@marcelkalveram/upgrading-react-native-to-version-0-59-and-beyond-a-step-by-step-guide-d4c2926dd482) ..Otherwise for rest versions your document is perfect.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

I have raised this query and answered myself as I was searching some helpful documentation to upgrade React native version.

Please find the below link which was really useful:

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/